# What is the difference between constructor and static code for "Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler" function

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the difference between constructor and static code?

Why `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`  can not work in constructor?

Source code 1:

```
class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("caught " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public class CaughtExceptionThread extends Thread{

    static {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
    }
}
```

Source code 2:

```
class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("caught " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public class CaughtExceptionThread extends Thread{

    public CaughtExceptionThread() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
public class DefaultExceptionHandler extends CaughtExceptionThread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService es =
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        es.execute(new ExceptionThread());
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Why source code 1 is working but source code 2 is not?

Comment: The constructor doesn't get called because you're not calling it.

Comment: Yes your are right, my mistake.